# Banach space of discontinuous functions(Killing continuous functions)

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, banach-spaces

**Edit:** According to the  comment of  Prof. Majer, I revise the question:

For  a  metric  space $X$, we put $A=\{f:X\to \mathbb{C}\mid \text{f is  bounded}\}$. We define two semi norm on $A$

$$\parallel f \parallel_{1}= \parallel \omega_{f}\parallel_{\infty}$$ or $$\parallel f \parallel_{2}= \int_{[0,\;1]} \omega_{f}(x)dx$$

where $\omega_{f}$ is the  standard [oscillation  function.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematics_of_oscillation).(**Edit:** In the  later norm, we put $X=[0\;1]$)

We obtain two  normed space on an  appropriate quotient space. Are these resulting space,  complete? After  a  possible  completion how can we compare them with each other and how can we compare them with $A/C$ where $C$ is the space  continuous  functions and $A$ is  equipped with sup norm. (By  comparison I mean comparison as two  Banach  space). What type of  topological or  metric  properties of $X$ is encoded in each of the  above  three  Banach  space. To what extent the  endomorphism of these Banach  space is  classified.(Motivated by the fact that the endomorphisms of $C(X)$, as  a  banach  space, are  classified)

Comment: "Appropriate quotient space" Do you have an idea how this space looks like (or how the space which you divide by)? I guess the quotient contains all characteristic functions of all points and then it wouldn't be separable in the first norm. The second norm looks pretty weired to me…

Comment: The second semi-norm is considered in the particular case of $X=[0,1]$, it seems. It vanishes exactly on the Riemann integrable functions.

Comment: @Dirk thanks for your comment on separability.regarding the second norm, as it is commented above, the quotient is dividing by riemann integrable functions.

Answer (score 4):

Let $f\in A$ and $r>\|\omega_f\|_\infty/2$. By definition of $\omega_f$, for any $x\in X$ there is a nbd $U$ of $x$ such that for all $y\in U$ one has  $|f(x)-f(y)|\le2r$, so that  $B(f(y),r) \cap B(f(x),r)\neq\emptyset .$

As a consequence, the closed convex valued multi map $F:X\to 2^\mathbb{C}$ defined by $F(x):=\overline {B(f(x),r)}$  is lower hemicontinuous. By [Michael  selection theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Michael_selection_theorem#Other_selection_theorems) there exists a continuous selection $g(x)\in F(x)$, therefore verifying  $\|f-g\|_\infty \le r.$

This proves that

$$\inf_{g\in C}\|f-g\|_\infty \le \|\omega_f\|_\infty/2.$$

that is, the quotient norm on $A/C$ induced by $\|\cdot\|_\infty$ is not larger than $\|\cdot\|_1/2$. On the other hand, for all $f\in A$, one has $ \|f\|_1 \le 2\|f\|_\infty,$ so that the norm induced on $A/C$  by $\|\cdot\|_1$ is exactly twice the quotient norm of $\|\cdot\|_\infty$. In particular, it is complete.

Comment: Prof.  Majer  thank you very much  for  your interesting  answer  and the  beautiful  application of  Michael  selection lemma  which  you mentioned.